# Discord welcome message private

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, message

I found a bot that automatically sends private messages when a person joins except that the bot crashes 3x a day and I don't know how to prevent it
Here is the error:

```
/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154
throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/949780165477679154/messages',
code: 50007,
httpStatus: 403
```

And here is my code :

```js
const { group } = require('console')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => console.log(`${client.user.tag} welcome yes`));

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let membersCount = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        client.user.setActivity(`Bou welcome`, {type: "PLAYING"});
    }, 1000 * 60);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    let guild = member.guild
    member.send('**Hey welcome to __' + guild.name + '__ ');
});

client.login("MY TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 1):

add a `.catch(()=> {})` to the end of `member.send('**Hey welcome to __'+guild.name+'__ ')`.

The bot cannot send dm messages to users who have blocked the bot or have disabled direct messages.